# RewriteRule isn't working.

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Doesn't work RewriteRule

```
RewriteRule .*find-a-bar/london/social-eating-house. /find-a-bar/london/the-blind-pig-at-social-eating-house [R=301,L]
```

when i type doamin.com/find-a-bar/london/social-eating-house nothing happen

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that your regex (once the period is removed) will match some URIs you may not expect e.g.

```
something/find-a-bar/london/social-eating-house
```

Try:

```
^find-a-bar/london/social-eating-house$
```

Which explicitly states the beginning and the end of the string you're trying to match.

Answer (score 0):

RewriteRule .*find-a-bar/london/social-eating-house. /find-a-bar/london/the-blind-pig-at-social-eating-house [R=301,L] is the answer

Answer (score 0):

Not working regex:

```
.*find-a-bar/london/social-eating-house.
```

As you can see you are using `.*` greedy matching here and hence underlying regex engine of mod_rewrite might be matching full regex using `.*`. Better to use **non-greedy** matching pattern like this (with line start and end anchors):

```
^.*?find-a-bar/london/social-eating-house/?$
```

Your rule should be:

```
RewriteRule ^.*?find-a-bar/london/social-eating-house/?$ /find-a-bar/london/the-blind-pig-at-social-eating-house [R=302,L,NC]
```

Only after you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.